# Using org-babel to enable virtualenv

Tags: org-babel, org-mode

I hoped to enable a virtualenv with org-babel source block before executing some python.

I wanted to do something like [pyenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) pyvenv-workon before it evaulates my code block. I didn't want to have to manually enable the virtualenv.

Something like,

```
#+NAME: elasticsearch_dsl_test
#+BEGIN_SRC: python :prologue "(pyvenv-workon 'elasticsearch)"
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q

client = Elasticsearch()

search = Search(using=client, index="localdev-news-newsentry")
response = search.execute()

print ["No response", "Was successfull"][int(response.success())]
print "Response took {0}ms.".format(response.took)
#+END_SRC
```

I couldn't quite get it working.

Comment: Your use of `:prologue` will prepend the text as is to the src block. Unquote your prologue and make sure it doesn't return anything that would be prepended.

Comment: @mutbuerger is it even possible to do what I'm suggesting? I did more reading and prologue just appends to the start, so python would be interpreting my elisp which is not possible..

Comment: If you remove the quotes from your prologue, the sexp will be evaluated for its side-effects and whatever `pyvenv-workon` returns will be appended to the src block. Default value of `:prologue` is "", so to make sure nothing gets appended you may use `:prologue (progn (pyvenv-workon 'elasticsearch) "")`.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working with multiple virtualenvs concurrently using org-babel `:session` and [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv).

**Note** that `scratchenv-SNmPgRMB` is the name of one of my personal environments created using [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) replace it with your virtualenv environment name.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :session venv-scratch
(pyvenv-workon "scratchenv-SNmPgRMB")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session venv-scratch
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
which python
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /home/costrouc/.virtualenvs/scratchenv-SNmPgRMB
: /home/costrouc/.virtualenvs/scratchenv-SNmPgRMB/bin/python

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session venv-scratch
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: /home/costrouc/.virtualenvs/scratchenv-SNmPgRMB/lib/python36.zip
: /home/costrouc/.virtualenvs/scratchenv-SNmPgRMB/lib/python3.6
: /home/costrouc/.virtualenvs/scratchenv-SNmPgRMB/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
: /usr/lib/python3.6
: /home/costrouc/.virtualenvs/scratchenv-SNmPgRMB/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

**Read paragraph if you need multiple concurrent virtualenvs**. One important thing to note about this approach is that you **must** run the shell and python interpreter once before adding another session with a different virtual environment. The reasoning for this is that when org-babel starts a session for `sh` and `python` it launches an interpreter. This means that at a minimum you need to run these three blocks before starting a new virtualenv session.